# Is it possible to get the tag of an union at runtime?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I am working on a new version of the [Spiral language](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language/tree/v0.2) and as one of its features, it will have structural equality and comparison similar to F#. But I am having difficulty figuring out how to compile that efficiently to F#.

The problem is that I cannot find how F# exposes tag information for its union cases.

For example, if I wrote `cmp a b` I'd like the Spiral compiler to generate something like the following F# code.

```fs
type T =
    | A of int32
    | B of float

let cmp_t = function
    | A x, A x' -> cmp_i32 (x, x')
    | B x, B x' -> cmp_f64 (x, x')
    | x, x' -> cmp_i32 (union_tag x, union_tag x')
```

I've looked around and there are some proposals to expose the tag information, but nothing is out yet. I am wondering whether the F# compiler library has some functionality that I am not aware of for extracting the tag.

Otherwise for every union type, I am going to have to generate a custom tag function like...

```fs
let tag_t = function
    | A _ -> 0
    | B _ -> 1
```

But this can't be the right choice because F# has to be using some kind of tag under the hood for each of the union cases in order to differentiate them. It has to be able to know the tag for its own comparison function. Making tag functions like these would bloat the generated code and would be inefficient at runtime.

What should I do here?

Answer (score 4):

You can use F# Reflection API for this.

[`Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-reflection-fsharptype.html#GetUnionCases) can return you a full list of DU cases, each represented as a `UnionCaseInfo` structure, which has such useful properties as `Name` and `Tag`:

```
> Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<T>) |> Array.map (fun c -> c.Tag)

[|0; 1|]
```

And if you have a concrete value of the type (like in your `cmp_t` function), check out [the `Reflection.FSharpValue.GetUnionFields` function](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-reflection-fsharpvalue.html#GetUnionFields), which, contrary to its name, will return you not only the fields, but also the `UnionCaseInfo` representing the case:

```
> let x = A 42
> let caseInfo, fields = Reflection.FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typeof<T>)
> caseInfo.Tag

0
```

Keep in mind, however, that for F# discriminated unions the compiler will generate structural comparison automatically, so your `cmpt_t` function is redundant:

```
> A 42 < A 54
true

> A 3 > B 1.0
false

// Or more generally:
> (A 42 :> System.IComparable<T>).CompareTo(A 54)
-1
```

So your cmp_t can really be just this:

```
let cmp_t (x: 'a when 'a :> System.IComparable<'a>) y = 
    (x :> System.IComparable<'a>).CompareTo(y)

> cmp_t (A 42) (A 54)
-1
```

And behold! There is already such function in the standard library. It's called [`compare`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#compare):

```
> compare (A 42) (A 54)
-1
```

Comment: This answer is worth an upvote, but it does not solve my problem completely. Even though this gives me a way to get the tag, the `Reflection.FSharpValue.GetUnionFields` is too inefficient given that it instantiates a type object at runtime and also returns an array of objects. If there was a function that was just `obj -> int`, I'd have no complaint here. Also, I was aware of `compare`, but that is no good to me given that Spiral has a typeclass mechanism. Not only am I going to have to do my own equality, comparison and hashing, I'll have to redo basic data structs like `Map`s from scratch.

Comment: I don't see what the type class system has to do with it. You can keep your existing `cmp_t` in place, and only use `compare` in the last branch, when the tags are different. This will have your desired effect while not using reflection.

Comment: This is a good idea. I'll go with it. Thank you.

Comment: I am debating internally whether to accept the answer, but I will hold off. The idea to use `compare` in the last branch is a good one, and is fine if the language is just targeting F#. Later though I will have a C backend at least, and possibly others, so I do not want very F# specific solutions in the core library. I'd prefer an uniform implementation of structural comparison, equality and hashing across a range of potential platforms and for that I need an efficient tag function. In the worst case, I might ditch F#'s inbuilt unions and compile them to objects in order to get this func.

Comment: Now that I am actually doing structural comparison, I see an issue with the `compare` idea. It cannot be partially evaluated. If some of the arguments are known at compile time there is no way to take advantage of this. Instead the I would be forced to push it all to runtime. I can't use it after all. I'll have to go for a stopgap measure for the time being, whether the be using the reflection function or generating my own tagging functions. Probably the first one. Later, when [the union tag](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/222) proposal gets implemented I'll replace it.